# Start matrix loop from block ID

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to start a matrix loop from a particular block ID?

I am trying to set a new block called "New Page" so that an author can split an article into multiple pages.

Currently it's able to detect a page break and exit out of the block field loop. I have also identified the next block's ID.

`{% set nextBlockAfterPageBreak = contentBlock.getNext().id %}`

Now what I'd like to be able to do is to get all blocks from `nextBlockAfterPageBreak`.

So for example,

`{% for contentBlock in matrixField where firstBlock = 237 %}`

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`offset` works for matrix blocks the same way it does for [entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#offset).

So you can do this to skip the first 12

```
{# skip the first 12 blocks #}
{% for contentBlock in matrixField.offset(12) %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by using this...

`{% for contentBlock in matrixField.id('>=237') %}`

In reality 237 is defined in a segment.

But it occurred to me that the ID of the block isn't necessarily the order of the block within the Matrix - for example if I add a new block and that's given an ID of 200, and I drag it up - it still remains as 200.

`ID != Position`

So to resolve this I took advantage of `loop.index0` to identify the true order of the row. I then wrap the switch statement within a conditional...

`{% if loop.index0>=craft.request.getSegment(3) %}`

Now I can output only the rows after the page break.